# Does OpenVswitch support BFD?

Tags: mininet, openvswitch

How to use BFD in OpenVswitch ?
any practical steps to test BFD in OpenVswitch will be appreciated .

cordially!

Answer (score 0):

The workflow should be something like this:

Assume you have:

- machine0 with eth1 having IP 192.168.1.1, and
- machine1 with eth1 having IP 192.168.1.2

On machine0
- Create a bridge:

```
ovs-vsctl add-br br0
```

- Add a port to this bridge (in this case, I am adding a GRE tunnel as
  a port with a remote end point of 192.168.1.2)

ovs-vsctl add-port br0 gre0 -- set interface gre0 type=gre options:remote_ip:192.168.1.2

- Enable bfd on that tunnel

ovs-vsctl set interface gre0 bfd:enable=true

Now repeat the same on machine1. You will have bfd traffic going between them.